# How can I connect to the internet using these items?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

My ISP told me they will connect me to the internet in 2 weeks, and sent me a cable modem which I received.

Right now I have access to a wifi connection which I am using with my ipod now, a cable modem, and a router. Can I connect to the internet using these?

It seems like the router can only make the internet coming through the modem into the router, wireless, right?

Isn't the router supposed to connect to any wireless connection too?

Answer (score 2):

The cable modem is plugged into your co-ax cable that comes from your cable provider.

The router (which in your case is the D-Link DIR-615) plugs into the cable modem using CAT 5 Ethernet cable. Most cable modems have one port, which is the one you'll use.

You'll connect the WAN (Internet) port on your D-Link to the cable modem.

The four LAN ports are for the inside of your network, to connect local devices like desktop PC, PlayStation, etc.

That should be it.

Comment: I have dlink dir-615.

Comment: Also should I connect modem to the router's LAN or internet input? Because there is 1 internet input but 4 LAN inputs.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks I used 1 cable to connect the modem to the router but after that how I connect either to my PC? Should I use the LAN inputs on the router because there is no other place to plug an ethernet cable from the PC to these devices.

Comment: The PC can use an Ethernet cable from the router, in one of the four LAN ports, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Randolph I did it that way anyway but the router setup still fails (not sure if that's necessary) but also windows still shows no internet connection using the new connection.

Comment: You may need to speak to your ISP to get the configuration right. It may not work out the box.

Comment: I see what you mean. Would I still need this info since ISP guys wont activate it for 2 weeks.

Comment: That I cannot answer. Good luck with the ISP!